# targeting screen for line item

Tags: visualforce, picklist

I have custom object line item which is a child object of opportunity.For any line item i have some targeting fields like age, gender etc. These fields are in Line item object. But i have a separate tab(object) called targeting attributes which contains all field of targeting screen.

The picklist values for every targeting attribute is stored as targeting value which is child object of targeting attribute.So i have a targeting screen which is displayed on line item detail page.

I want the fields of targeting screen to be controlling and dependent. In targeting screen code they are not referring any field by its name. They are just iterating over all targeting attributes to display them. In targeting screen i want that if user select gender as male, other field in targeting screen should show only a specific values. Could anyone please advise.

Below is the code of my EditTargeting page-

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Line_Item__c" extensions="Cntrl_EditTargeting,Cntrl_CityTargeting" tabstyle="Line_Item__c" action="{!take_snapshot}"> 
<apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" />
<apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js" />
<apex:stylesheet value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.geo_css}" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("formTbl").focus();
    }
</script>
<style>
.Error { color: red; font-weight: strong;}

</style>
<apex:messages styleClass="Error"/>
<apex:PageBlock title="Opportunity: {!Line_Item__c.Opportunity_Name__r.Name}:: Line Item: {!Line_Item__c.name}">

    <apex:form id="form" >
        <table  border="0" width="100%" id="formTbl">
            <tr>
                <td  align="left" width="30%" href="#anchor">
                    <apex:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Save Targeting" action="{!doSave}" />
                </td>
                <td  align="left" width="30%" href="#anchor">
                    <apex:commandButton id="saveTargetingBtn" value="Save Targeting and Edit Line" action="{!targetingSave}" />
                </td>
                <td  align="left" width="20%">
                    <font size="2" color="blue">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!goCancel}" />
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td  align="right" nowrap="true" width="10%">
                    <font size="2" color="blue">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Line Item" action="{!goToLine}" />
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td align="right" nowrap="true" width="10%">
                    <font size="2" color="blue">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Opportunity" action="{!goToOppty}" /> 
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <apex:repeat value="{!targetAttLists}" var="s">
                <tr>

                    <td  colspan="3" width="100%">
                        <c:TargetingTable line="{!line}" fields="{!s.attList}" mode="Edit" sectionName="{!s.section}"/> 
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>

             <tr>
                <td  align="left" width="30%">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save Targeting" action="{!doSave}" />
                </td>
                <td  align="left" width="30%" href="#anchor">
                    <apex:commandButton id="saveTargetingEditLine" value="Save Targeting and Edit Line" action="{!targetingSave}" />
                </td>
                <td  align="left"  width="20%">
                    <font size="2" color="blue">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!goCancel}" />
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td  align="right" nowrap="true" width="10%">
                    <font size="2" color="blue">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Line Item" action="{!goToLine}" />
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td align="right" nowrap="true" width="10%">
                    <font size="2" color="blue">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Opportunity" action="{!goToOppty}" /> 
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:PageBlock>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
    var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
            var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
            if(KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch){
                return KeyValuePair[1];
            }
        }   
    }

    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // Create City autopopulate
    var City = $('.dataCol:contains(City Targeting)').find('textarea');
    (function($,City){
    City.hide();
    var container = City.parent(),
            auto = $('<input type="text" />').appendTo(container),
            tar = $('<ul class="target" />').appendTo(container);
    $(City.val().split(',')).each(function(i,e){ e=e.trim(); if(e.length>0){ $('<li />').text(e).appendTo(tar); } });               
    tar.trigger('change');
    auto.autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        delay: 350,
        source: function(request,callback){
            var country = GetUrlValue('country');   
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                'Cntrl_CityTargeting.getOptions',
                'City', country,request.term,
                function(result, event){                    
                    callback(result);                       
                }
            );          
        },
        select: function(event, ui){
            var val = ui.item.value;
            if(tar.find('li:contains('+val+')').length==0){
                $('<li />').text(val).appendTo(tar);
            }
            tar.trigger('change');
            container.find('input').val('');
            return false;
        }
    }); 
    tar.on('change',function(evt){
        var ul = $(this),
            lis = ul.find('li'),
            els = [];
        if(lis.length > 0){
            $.each(lis,function(i,e){ 
                e=$(e); 
                if(e.find('span.x').length==0){
                    e.append($('<span class="x">x</span>'));
                }
                els.push(e.text().replace(/x$/,''));
                if(els.length>0){
                    City.text(els.join(', '));
                }
            }); 
        }
        else{
            City.text('');
        }               
    });
    tar.on('click','span.x',function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var x = $(this),
        li = x.parent('li').fadeOut(400,function(){ 
            li.remove(); 
            tar.trigger('change'); 
        });
    }); 
})($,City);
$('ul.target').trigger('change');
       });
      </script>
      </apex:page>
```

Please help.

Comment: Welome to SF.SE user19185. Are you using the Non Profit Starter Pack? Opportunity Line Item is for Products that one is selling. Your question makes no sense in that context. In the NPSP, Opportunity is used for donations, in that context, your question *might* make a bit more sense. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).